# Can I Open a Workbook via a Proxy in VBA?

Tags: vba, proxy

Is there any way to define proxy settings to open a particular workbook with?

I've found some info here about proxy setting in vb but I don't have the understanding to convert this to vba: http://ankurm.com/labblog/programmatically-set-proxy-settings-in-visual-basic/

Comment: What's the relationship/connection/rationale between opening a workbook and a network proxy?

Comment: User opens a workbook which itself opens another workbook that's stored on an extranet site (to check user info). When a client is using it from outside our network uses it it fails because the workbook can't access the user info workbook.